# comparing two arrayLists for match a condition for postprocessing

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two arraylists

```
ArrayList A ArrayList B
London      001
Berlin      001
Frankfurt   450
Rome        001
Geneva      230
Lille       620
```

What, I am trying to print out is the following:
If, the code in the arraylist are not equal then add separate XML tags to it. if they are equal then club them in a single tag.

E.g

```
<001> London Berlin </001> <450> Frankfurt </450> <001> Rome </001> <230> Geneva </230> <620> Lille </620>
```

Below is the logic which I am using

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i= 0; i< ListA.size(); i++){            
            if(i >=1){              
                String temp = ListB.get(i-1);               
                if(temp.contentEquals(ListB.get(i)))
                {                   
                    newList.add(ListA.get(i));                  
                }
                else{                   
                    newList.add("<"+ ListB.get(i) +"> " + ListA.get(i) + " </"+ ListB.get(i) +">" );
                }   
            }
            else{   
             /*if i=0*/
             newList.add("<"+ ListB.get(i) +"> " + ListA.get(i) + " </"+ ListB.get(i) +">" );
            }       

        }       

        StringJoiner outputText = new StringJoiner(" ");
        for(int i=0; i< newList.size();i++){
            outputText.add(newList.get(i));         
        }

        System.out.println(outputText.toString());
    }
```

I understand there is a problem with the logic. Just got lost in loops.

Comment: There seems to be an inconsistency with the searching for `equals`(contentEquals) code? Why not try to sort the array first? Then printing code is just straight forward.

Comment: Why is `Rome` and `London Berlin` in different tags?

Comment: In the end we need to maintain the order of the list. Hence they are not mixed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your logic was wrong, try this one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListA.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            newList.add("<" + ListB.get(i) + "> " + ListA.get(i) + " ");
        }
        if (i >= 1) {
            String temp = ListB.get(i - 1);
            if (temp.equals(ListB.get(i))) {
                newList.add(ListA.get(i));
            } else {
                newList.add("</" + ListB.get(i - 1) + ">" + " <" + ListB.get(i) + "> " + ListA.get(i) + " ");
            }
        }
        if (i == ListA.size() - 1) {
            newList.add("</" + ListB.get(i) + ">");
        }
    }
```

by using this logic you will have exactly the desired output

Answer (score 2):

see below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class MultipleLists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


//        London      001
//        Berlin      001
//        Frankfurt   450
//        Rome        001
//        Geneva      230
//        Lille       620



        List<String> cities = Arrays.asList("London", "Berlin", "Frankfurt", "Rome", "Geneva", "Lille");
        List<String> codes = Arrays.asList("001", "001", "450", "001", "230", "620");


        List<CityCode> cityCodes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++) {
            cityCodes.add(new CityCode(cities.get(i), codes.get(i)));
        }

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Collections.sort(codes);
        Set<String> codesSet = new HashSet<>(codes);

        for (String code : codesSet) {
            stringBuffer.append("<" + code + ">");

            for (CityCode cityCode : cityCodes) {
                if (cityCode.getCode().compareTo(code) == 0) {
                    stringBuffer.append(cityCode.getName());
                    stringBuffer.append(" ");
                }
            }
            stringBuffer.append("</" + code + ">");
        }

        System.out.println(stringBuffer);  // <001>London Berlin Rome </001><620>Lille </620><230>Geneva </230><450>Frankfurt </450>

    }
}

class CityCode {
    private String name;
    private String code;

    public CityCode(String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a minor change and that is to add the closing tags differently. Other code remains the same.

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i= 0; i< ListA.size(); i++){            
            if(i >=1){              
                String temp = ListB.get(i-1);               
                if(temp.contentEquals(ListB.get(i)))
                {                   
                    newList.add(ListA.get(i));                
                }else{    
                    newList.add(" </"+ ListB.get(i-1) +">" )               
                    newList.add("<"+ ListB.get(i) +"> " + ListA.get(i) );
                }   

            }else{   
             /*if i=0*/
             newList.add("<"+ ListB.get(i) +"> " + ListA.get(i) + );
            }  
            if(i==ListA.size()-1){
                newList.add(" </"+ ListB.get(i-1) +">" 
            }      

        }       

        StringJoiner outputText = new StringJoiner(" ");
        for(int i=0; i< newList.size();i++){
            outputText.add(newList.get(i));         
        }

        System.out.println(outputText.toString());
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> cities = Arrays.asList("London", "Berlin", "Frankfurt", "Rome", "Geneva", "Lille");
        List<String> codes = Arrays.asList("001", "001", "450", "001", "230", "620");

        Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++) {
            String city = cities.get(i);
            String code = codes.get(i);

            if (result.containsKey(code)) {
                List<String> list = result.get(code);
                list.add(city);
            } else {
                ArrayList<String> mappedCities = new ArrayList<>();
                mappedCities.add(city);
                result.put(code, mappedCities);
            }
        }

        String fullXml = result.entrySet().stream().parallel().map(entry -> {
            String tag = entry.getKey();
            List<String> vals = entry.getValue();
            String citiesSeparated = vals.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
            return xmlStart(tag) + citiesSeparated + xmlEnd(tag);
        }).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        System.out.println(fullXml);
    }

    private static String xmlEnd(String s) {
        return "<" + s + "/>";
    }

    private static String xmlStart(String s) {
        return "<" + s + ">";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: having two disconnected Lists is not a good idea (very bad idea). 
You highly depend on position of code and city in them. Maybe you can reconsider to use a Map instead? It will be much easier.

Second: it seems like you missed one requirement which is in your code.
"Join cities in one tag if code is equal to previous city code"
is it true or not? Why "Rome" with code 001 is in separate tag from "London Berlin"?

Third: Of course Jose's answer is correct OO answer which personally I prefer.

Forth: BTW if "Rome" must be in the same tag as "London Berlin" you can simply use a Map like:

```
    Map<String,String> codeCityMap = new TreeMap<String,String>();

    for (int i=0;i <arrayListA.size();i++)
    {
        String cities = codeCityMap.get(arrayListB.get(i));
        cities = null == cities?arrayListA.get(i):cities + " " + arrayListA.get(i);
        codeCityMap.put(arrayListB.get(i), cities);                 
    }

    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String code: codeCityMap.keySet())
    {
        newList.add("<" + code + ">" + codeCityMap.get(code) + "</" + code + ">");
    }
```

If "Rome" must not be you can use same technique, but introduce a little additional code to check also equality to to the previous citiy code in the line `cities = null == cities?arrayListA.get(i):cities + " " + arrayListA.get(i);`

if you need to main order or sort result use LinkedMap, TreeMap or do it on your own.